# Regex for Auto complete suggestions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a search bar, and this is my current regex.

```
 const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`,'i')
```

My data is something like

Google Services 10239
Adobe Services 10921

They all have their own unique ID

My code works if I type "Go" then it auto suggests google which works!

the issue is if I type its number 10239 it doesn't work anymore.

Now I could just reverse the order, and it should work but is there any easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `^` from your regex. Or if you want your autocomplete to pick up beginnings of words only, you can try replacing the `^` with a `\b` like so

```
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${value}`, 'i')
```

or even

```
 const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`\b${value}`, 'i')
```

Comment: Looks like its just returning everything that has that letter in any place. I guess ill just force the results to only be 3... or something.

Comment: Right, without the `^` it is a substring search for something anywhere in the string. Try the `\b`.

Comment: That worked great. Thank you ill mark you as answer in 5 mins